# How to make two divs fit a desired width and avoid wrapping and overlapping?

Tags: css, html

I'm using relative widths:

```
<style>
    #ldiv {
        height: 400px;
        width: 75%;
        background-color:#fff;
        color:#ccc;
        border: 1px solid #F2F2F2;
        float: left;
    }

    #rdiv {
        vertical-align: top;
        float: left;
        width: 25%;
    }
</style>

<div>
    <div id="ldiv">Left</div>
    <div id="rdiv">Right</div>
</div>
```

With this code, `#rdiv` doesn't stay beside `#ldiv`.
If I use `margin-right: -2px;` in `#ldiv`, the two divs stay side by side, but overlap slightly.

I know the problem is caused by the border, but how can I make it fit?

Comment: Setting `width:74%` on `#ldiv` fixes it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

write like this:

```
#ldiv {
    height: 400px;
    background-color:#fff;
    color:#ccc;
    border: 1px solid #F2F2F2;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#rdiv {
    vertical-align: top;
    float: right;
    width: 25%;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <div id="rdiv">Right</div>
    <div id="ldiv">Left</div>  
</div>
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/aYteE/

**OR**

You can use `box-sizing` property for this.

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/aYteE/2/

Comment: It didn't work... #ldiv takes 100% of the width and #rdiv is placed below it.

Comment: Not really... It's pretty simple: I want two divs to fit together. #ldiv won't increase in width, but the #rdiv can. If #rdiv gets wider, it must have a fixed width so it wraps content inside it.

Answer (score 1):

use a super div and position the inner divs with position:relative and float:left. Avoid giving width to the second div because border will make it go over "100%".

```
#container {
    width:100%;
}
#ldiv {
    height: 400px;
    width: 75%;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    background-color:#fff;
    color:#ccc;
    border: 1px solid #F2F2F2;
    float: left;
}

#rdiv {
    vertical-align: top;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
}

<div id="container">
    <div id="ldiv">Left</div>
    <div id="rdiv">Right</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I did small changes thats it. Friend please check it.

## ldiv {

float:left;
    height: 400px;
    width: 75%;
    background-color:#545149;
    color:#ccc;
    border: 1px solid #F2F2F2;
}

## rdiv {

float:left;
   padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;
}

Comment: postion:relative; and u giving float;; hmm actually ur stoped browser inatligence to work with ur postion command. when size and resolution incresse its tottaly misplaced. !!